# API and static html served from same directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, lamp

I am on a shared hosting and from my directory I want to serve both static pages and requests from api server (written with symfony php). I have a /static folder with index.html etc. and a /myapi folder with the symfony project, containing the index.php in the top level. Now I want requests to e.g. mywhateverdomain.com/somepage to target /static/somepage/index.html and all requests to mywhateverdomain.com/api/* to target the symfony app, in other words /myapi/index.php. How do I have to set up my .htaccess? I also want both to redirect to https. Thanks a lot in advance!